# Create dynamic object with a for loop

Tags: javascript

Here's an idea of what I'm after:

```
{ 'this id0': function() {
  console.log(0);
  },

  'this id1': function() {
    console.log(1);
  },

  ...
  ...
}
```

I thought I'd try something like:

```
var foo = {};
for (var i = 0, len < 10; i < len; i++)
  foo['this id'[i]] = function() {console.log([i]};
```

I'm unclear on the correct syntax to use.

Comment: `'this id'[i]` ➡ `'this id'+i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keys are strings, so you need to concatenate `'this id'` to `i`:

```
var foo = {};
for (var i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    foo['this id' + i] = function() { console.log(i); }; 
}

foo['this id4'](); // logs 10
```

Comment: The above `console.log(foo['this id4']())` logs *undefined*

Comment: Fixed. It actually did log both `10` and `undefined`.

Comment: Firefox still logs *undefined* while Chrome logs both *10* and *undefined*

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/anq29khg/ doesn't log `undefined` for me in firefox or chrome.

Comment: I was testing directly on the console for both browsers. But it doesn't really matter since the code structure is correct

Answer (score 1):

Object attributes must be valid string when accessing using square brackets:

```
foo['this id' + String(i)]
```

Add this to the for loop

Comment: Concatenation automatically converts to string. Casting was not necessary

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but it's good practice to cast to String explicitly!